# Can we have Multiple AWS Cloudfront Distribution with same subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have two cloudfront distributions, Eg: E1Axx and E1Bxx.
I have created a subdomain `test.com` and added that to E1Axx (updated cname, index.html, certs etc). So now I can access `test.com/index.html` (configured on E1Axx)

Can I use this same subdomain `test.com` for E1Bxx? ie, can I configure the same `cname` and certs and a different root index page in E1Bxx to use the same subdomain? Is it allowed? Or do we need to create another subdomain for E1Bxx? Could someone please advise?
Thanks in advance!

Would like to clarify if this is allowed in AWS, before requesting for a new subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will use DNS to point the domain to a distribution, you can only point it to a single distribution (technically you can have multiple DNS records that point the same domain to different locations, but only a single pointer record will be returned per request to DNS, so for functional purposes it's a 1 to 1 relationship).
If you had actual subdomains, like a.test.com and b.test.com then they could be pointed to different CloudFront distributions.

What goal are you trying to accomplish by having the same domain go to 2 different distributions?